# Prepend phone numbers with a calling card dial in number

Tags: phone-app

I use a calling card to call my home country and usually it's these steps:

1. Call the dial in number for the calling card company (e.g. 1 800 123 1234)
2. Enter the card PIN code (e.g. 1234 1234 1234)
3. Enter the destination number (which is saved as a phone in the contacts - e.g. +7 12 123456780)

I have several several contacts I call regularly and also plenty of one-offs.

Is there an app or way to automatically prefix the numbers from steps 1 & 2 along with pauses (p) and waits (w) so that I could dial the contact directly from the address book?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Prefixer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tftbelow.prefixer), which lets you "prefix, suffix and/or replace numbers in your calls" -- sounds like exactly what you need. There are a few similar apps on the Playstore:

- [Prefix Dialer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.eriksundin.prefixdialer)
- [Number Fixer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maplekeycompany.apps.numberfixer)
- [PreFixer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.sogeti.prefixer)

I'm pretty sure one of them will solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you! Prefixer (the first one mentioned in the first sentence) did exactly what I was looking for and is capable of even more!

Comment: Thank you for including what finally did it! :) Glad I was able to help!